# Python Imaging: load jpeg from memory

Tags: python, image, jpeg

The problem is to load jpeg-encoded image from memory.

I receive a string from socket:

```
jpgdata = self.rfile.read(sz)
```

and I know that this is jpeg-encoded image.

I need to decode it.
The most stupid solution is:

```
o = open("Output/1.jpg","wb")
o.write(jpgdata)
o.close()
dt = Image.open("Output/1.jpg")
```

The question is how to do the same thing in-memory?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

PIL's Image.open object accepts any file-like object. That means you can wrap your Image data on a StringIO object, and pass it to Image.Open

```
from io import BytesIO
file_jpgdata = BytesIO(jpgdata)
dt = Image.open(file_jpgdata)
```

Or, try just passing `self.rfile` as an argument to Image.open - it might work just as well. (That is for Python 3 - for Python 2 use `from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO`)

Answer (score 0):

Use StringIO so Image can access your data as if it were a file.