# Python FedEx Image Stream to Image

Tags: python, fedex, imagestream

I am trying to automate my shipping process using the Python fedex module. I am using developer test credentials. The code to create my shipment can be seen here:

```
import fedex
from fedex.services.ship_service import FedexProcessShipmentRequest, FedexDeleteShipmentRequest
from fedex.config import FedexConfig
CONFIG_OBJ = FedexConfig(key='******',
                         password= '*****',
                         account_number='***',
                         meter_number='***',
                         use_test_server=True)

shipment = FedexProcessShipmentRequest(CONFIG_OBJ)
shipment = FedexProcessShipmentRequest(CONFIG_OBJ)

shipment.RequestedShipment.DropoffType = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'
shipment.RequestedShipment.ServiceType = 'FEDEX_GROUND'
shipment.RequestedShipment.PackagingType = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'

shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Contact.PersonName = 'Sender Name'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Contact.PhoneNumber = '9012638716'

shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address.StreetLines = ['Address Line 1']
shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address.City = 'Detroit'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address.StateOrProvinceCode = 'Mi'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address.PostalCode = '48127'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Shipper.Address.CountryCode = 'US'

shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Contact.PersonName = 'Recipient Name'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Contact.PhoneNumber = '9012637906'

shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.StreetLines = ['Address Line 1']
shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.City = 'Detroit'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.StateOrProvinceCode = 'Mi'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.PostalCode = '48127'
shipment.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.CountryCode = 'US'
shipment.RequestedShipment.EdtRequestType = 'NONE'

shipment.RequestedShipment.ShippingChargesPayment.Payor.ResponsibleParty.AccountNumber \
    = CONFIG_OBJ.account_number

shipment.RequestedShipment.ShippingChargesPayment.PaymentType = 'SENDER'

shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelFormatType = 'COMMON2D'
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.ImageType = 'PNG'
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelStockType = 'PAPER_7X4.75'
shipment.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelPrintingOrientation = 'BOTTOM_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST'
```

The code executes without problem and outputs the following JSON:

```
    (reply){
   HighestSeverity = "SUCCESS"
   Notifications[] = 
      (Notification){
         Severity = "SUCCESS"
         Source = "ship"
         Code = "0000"
         Message = "Success"
         LocalizedMessage = "Success"
      },
   Version = 
      (VersionId){
         ServiceId = "ship"
         Major = 23
         Intermediate = 0
         Minor = 0
      }
   JobId = "aac513eb0455f072033104594"
   CompletedShipmentDetail = 
      (CompletedShipmentDetail){
         UsDomestic = True
         CarrierCode = "FDXG"
         MasterTrackingId = 
            (TrackingId){
               TrackingIdType = "FEDEX"
               TrackingNumber = "794608334864"
            }
         ServiceTypeDescription = "FXG"
         ServiceDescription = 
            (ServiceDescription){
               ServiceType = "FEDEX_GROUND"
               Code = "92"
               Names[] = 
     ....
```

I would like to show the physical shipping label that the following subsection of the output points to:

```
Label = 
                      (ShippingDocument){
                         Type = "OUTBOUND_LABEL"
                         ShippingDocumentDisposition = "RETURNED"
                         ImageType = "PNG"
                         Resolution = 200
                         CopiesToPrint = 1
                         Parts[] = 
                            (ShippingDocumentPart){
                               DocumentPartSequenceNumber = 1
                               Image = "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"
                            },
                      }
```

However, I am unsure how to do this. Can anybody offer me any guidance?

Thank you!

Comment: That's base64. There's no API documentation saying as much? Decode it to bytes, then read in the stream like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821393/6273251). Were you not familiar with base64, or did you have some other question?

Comment: @RandomDavis. Thank you. Trying to decode this with ascII I get a decode error. When I investigate the type of the string it is <class 'suds.sax.text.Text'>. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: The type is just a subset of unicode (see [here])(https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803991/6273251). But I'm confused as to what you mean by "trying to decode this with ASCII". You should show what you're trying to do, and show the error, rather than just talking about it. It should be very straightforward to decode the string, using the method demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207978/python-converting-from-base64-to-binary).

Comment: @RandomDavis I found a solution to the decoding issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388965/how-to-write-a-base64-encoded-field-content-coming-from-suds-to-a-file-in-python). I fed the output into the code that you recommended...and voila! A shipping label. Thank you!